# Angular 2 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, jspm

I am trying to add jQuery to the Angular 2 project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-modern-web-dev) through `jspm`. 
As far as I can understand, I have to run

```
jspm install jquery
```

and then use

```
import {$} from "jquery"
```

in my components. But I get an error `Cannot find module 'jquery'`. 
What do I do wrong?

Comment: why not to use simple `jQuery` using npm ? i have solution using simple Jquery i dont know about jspm. if u feel need of same ill post it as answer,

Comment: Are you using Typescript?

Comment: Yes, I am using TypeScript.
@PardeepJain, I would be happy to see your solution with npm.

Comment: Is there a reason to use jQuery with Angular?  Angular (especially version 2) is *designed* to make direct DOM-manipulation with libraries like jQuery unnecessary.  I find that in 99% of the cases, there is a more Angular-idomatic way to do something instead of using jQuery.

Comment: When I started with Angular 1.X, I was loading jQuery.  Then progressively refined the pages to a state that I can just use jQuery.lite (included in Angular 1).  Then in the end I was able to remove almost every single call to jQuery.lite.

Comment: @Stephen Chung - I agree with your answer. But it is applicable when you have decided to write each component on your own from the scratch. But when you try to use `already used material made in Jquery` at that moment you always come with a question like `how can I use Jquery with Angular2`. This is truth at least for me. ;-)

Comment: Sigh... true... As I always say: One day our code will out-live us...

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the package manager, using a JavaScript library has less to do with the framework and more to do with integration into the language.

For TypeScript, you want to be sure you have the type definition for a given JavaScript library.

You can find a list of types via the [Types Search on GitHub](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/), powered by [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and [types-publisher](https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher).

So, for the jQuery type via NPM...

```
npm install --save @types/jQuery
```

From there, be sure to include the type declaration in your TypeScript file...

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

Then, just start using jQuery as usual!

```
$(".button").css({ marginTop: value });
```

See the jQuery example in [the Samples section of the TypeScript Language site](http://www.typescriptlang.org/samples/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

With JSPM I believe it should be

```
import $ from "jquery"
```

and make sure you make TypeScript happy with

```
declare var $;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this fails with error `Cannot find module 'jquery'`. I would appreciate it you take a look at the test project
https://github.com/SergeyMell/angular2-test-project

Answer (score 0):

With `NPM` i installed `jQuery` using command line using

```
npm install jQuery --save
```

then import the dependencie into the Index.html file

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

and in your `component` class at the bottom (outside of the exported class abc{} type)

```
declare var jQuery: any
```

then you will be able to use jQuery('#anything')....

Comment: That works in dev mode, but fails on production... I think that could be connected with some project generator instructions. Would you be so kind as too look at it?
https://github.com/SergeyMell/angular2-test-project

Comment: did't tested with `production mode` yet...may be error occurred not sure

Comment: The only solution I found is to inject script into index.html with **inline** property as 
`<script inline src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`
That works but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: yes of course we have to import the script file in the index.html . i think this is the only solution.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with angular-cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/847#issuecomment-223178800

Answer (score 0):

`npm install jquery -s`

import to component

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Use test in component

`console.log($);`

return in browser console F12

this: `function ( selector, context ) {`

Other example with moment

`npm install moment -s`

`import * as moment from 'moment';`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2, in order to import jquery,

```
import $ from "jquery"
```

you should map key (jquery) with its source file in **systemjs.config.js**

```
'jquery': 'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
```